# How to change the number of links in the pagination block? (Laravel 8)

Tags: laravel, pagination, laravel-8

I use Laravel Framework 8 (8.83.23). Please help me understand how to set a limit on the number of links.

I have this (custom template in `views/vendor/pagination`):

[image]

And want to get this:

[image]

Already tried this:

```
/** In controller */
public function index()
{
    return view('pages.products.index')
        ->with(
            'products',
            Product::latest()
                ->paginate(12)
                ->onEachSide(2)
        );
}
```

And this (without using onEachSide in controller):

```
/** In blade */
<div class="row py-5">
    <div class="col-auto mx-auto">
        {{ $products->onEachSide(2)->links() }}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want it on all pages or only one of them ?

Comment: @JSTECH I want it on all pages :)

Comment: You can play around with the pagination data in `resources/views/vendor/pagination` directory  by running `php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-pagination` command.

Comment: @JSTECH I set up the template there. It seems that you will have to make the rules for displaying links before and after the separator yourself.

Comment: Perhaps, I should say "YEAH!".